# blueprint properties without calling route

Tags: java, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to initialize some attributes with value in blueprint. However, the cm:property can only be initialized when route is called. But I want to initialize when the bean is created without calling route. What should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:config="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <!-- define configuration properties -->
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.tommyqu.common" update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="activemq.group.name" value="edpDev" />
            <cm:property name="event.destinationQueue" value="edp-event" /> 
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <bean id="eventBean" class="com.tommyqu.EventBean">
        <property name="queueGroupName" value="${activemq.group.name}" />
        <property name="eventQueueName" value="${event.destinationQueue}" />
    </bean>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Can you better explain what your problem is, its unclear

Comment: @Claus Ibsen I'm trying to inject properties' value to Java. With the above code, the Java output value of these properties will be null.

Comment: @Claus Ibsen I already create the setter functions.

Comment: Which OSGi container are you using? The bean should have all the properties injected when it gets created. Can you post the bean code with the related setters?

Comment: @Alessandro Da Rugna Thanks Alees. I find that with blueprint xmlns configuration, we can't initialize the properties's value in Bean without routes. Only with Spring Beans configuration, we can initialize the property values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not mandatory to declare a route but the property injection will work only if you set up a CamelContext.

You can try to declare an empty Camel Context like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:config="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <!-- define configuration properties -->
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.tommyqu.common" update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="activemq.group.name" value="edpDev" />
            <cm:property name="event.destinationQueue" value="edp-event" /> 
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <!-- No routes declared --> 
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="eventBean" class="com.tommyqu.EventBean">
        <property name="queueGroupName" value="${activemq.group.name}" />
        <property name="eventQueueName" value="${event.destinationQueue}" />
    </bean>
</blueprint>
```

In that case you don't need a route but you declare a context so that property replacement is working.